# Reverse to Yii2 swiftmailer\Message toString()

Tags: php, yii2, swiftmailer

I am trying to to send mail which is made of database stored information. I will try to describe what I am doing in steps.

- I am composing mail from view file
- I am converting it to string
- Saving that string into database

----> Now I need to do reverse

- I am fetching that string I just saved
- I need to compose mail out of that string (this is the part I can get right)

Maybe someone could help me with this problem?